# Как сравнить два списка в любой последовательности?

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 1]
```

Как сравнить два этих списка, чтобы засчитать, что они равные, чтобы вышло значение True

Comment: Отсортировать, потом сравнить.

Comment: [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 5):

Исходные списки:

```
a = [1, 1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 1]
c = [4, 5, 6]
```

Сортируем и сравниваем:

```
a.sort()
b.sort()
c.sort()
a == b # True
a == c # False
b == c # False
```

Почему нельзя сделать `a.sort() == b.sort()`? Дело в том, что метод `sort` изменяет исходный список и возвращает значение `None`. Таким образом выражение `a.sort() == b.sort()` всегда будет `True`.

Как правильно указал Jazzis также можно использовать функцию `sorted`, она возвращает отсортированный список:

```
a = [1, 1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 1]
a == b # False
sorted(a) == sorted(b) # True
```

Comment: Можно ведь `sorted(a) == sorted(b)`.

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказку, забыл про `sorted`. С Вашего позволения, добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 2):

еще один вариант, основанный на удалении одинаковых элементов.

```
a = [1,2,1,4]
b = [4,1,1,2]
c = [1,1,1,4]

def eq_elements(x,y):
    if len(x) != len(y): return False
    for z in y:
        try:
            x.remove(z)
        except:
            return False
    return True

rez = eq_elements(a[:],b)

print (f"lists elements  is {'' if rez else 'not' } equal ")
```

хотя данный алгоритм в среднем затратнее алгоритма с сортировкой, однако на списках, вообще не имеющих одинаковых элементов, он срабатывает на первом же элемете, в то время как алгоритм с сортировкой всегда не менее чем O(n*log2(n)) операций.

при передаче параметров я написал `a[:]`, так как в функции первый параметр (список x) портится удалением. Запись `a[:]`  просто создает копию списка.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 1]
print(sorted(a) == sorted(b))
```

Вывод:

```
True
```

Comment: Такой ответ уже есть

Comment: Похожий код есть, не обратил сразу внимание.

Comment: @CrazyElf  В данном случае [вполне можно и продублировать](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9459/217579).

Comment: @0xdb Ну, если правила разрешают... Так то я согласен, что тут суть сразу видно, а в том ответе до неё надо ещё домотать.

Answer (score 2):

[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) - идиоматическое решение для сравнения коллекций без учёта порядка. Плюс он работает быстрее чем сортировка:

```
import collections

a = [1, 1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 1]

print(collections.Counter(a) == collections.Counter(b))
```